# Cannot invoke chaincode with non-admin Identity / User context - Hyperledger Fabric - Node SDK

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been trying to invoke my chaincode with ABAC and am unable to invoke the chaincode as a registered user of the network but can invoke it as an admin. I need to invoke as a user to check ABAC.

**Enrolling Admin:**

```
const FabricClient = require('fabric-client');
const path = require('path');
var fabric_client = new FabricClient();
var Fabric_CA_Client = require('fabric-ca-client');
var user = null;
var admin = null;

module.exports.enrollAdmin = async function (orgName, mspID, caPort) {
    try {
        var store_path = path.join(__dirname, orgName + '-key-store');
        var keyValueStore = await FabricClient.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path });
        console.log('Key store path detected');
        console.log('Store -> ' + JSON.stringify(keyValueStore));
        fabric_client.setStateStore(keyValueStore);
        var crypto_suite = FabricClient.newCryptoSuite();
        var cryptoKeyStore = FabricClient.newCryptoKeyStore({ path: store_path });
        crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(cryptoKeyStore);
        fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

        var tlsOptions = {
            trustedRoots: [],
            verify: false
        };

        fabric_CA_Client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:' + caPort, tlsOptions, 'ca-' + orgName, crypto_suite);

        var adminUser_from_store = await fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true);

        if (adminUser_from_store && adminUser_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
            console.log('Admin user already exists.');

            throw new Error('Admin already exists');
        } else {
            console.log('Enrolling admin.....');
            var enrollmentSecret = await fabric_CA_Client.enroll({
                enrollmentID: 'admin',
                enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw',
                attr_reqs: [
                    { name: "firstName", optional: false },
                    { name: "hf.Registrar.Attributes", optional: false }
                ]

            });
        }

        console.log('enrollment success');
        console.log('--------------------')
        var enrolledUser = await fabric_client.createUser({
            username: 'admin',
            mspid: mspID,
            cryptoContent: { privateKeyPEM: enrollmentSecret.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollmentSecret.certificate }
        });

        console.log('Enrolled User -> ' + enrolledUser);
        admin = enrolledUser;
        // console.log(admin);
        console.log('Admin successfully enrolled');
        await fabric_client.setUserContext(admin);
        return true;

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Registering User:**

```
const FabricClient = require('fabric-client');
const path = require('path');

var fabClient = new FabricClient();

var Fabric_CA_Client = require('fabric-ca-client');

var user = null;
var admin = null;
var memberUser = null;

module.exports.registerNewUser = async function (orgName, mspID, caPort, username) {

    try {
        var store_path = path.join(__dirname, orgName + '-key-store');
        var keyValueStore = await FabricClient.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path });

        console.log('Key store path detected');
        console.log('Store -> ' + JSON.stringify(keyValueStore));
        fabClient.setStateStore(keyValueStore);
        var crypto_suite = FabricClient.newCryptoSuite();
        var cryptoKeyStore = FabricClient.newCryptoKeyStore({ path: store_path });
        crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(cryptoKeyStore);
        fabClient.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

        var tlsOptions = {
            trustedRoots: [],
            verify: false
        };

        fabric_CA_Client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:' + caPort, tlsOptions, 'ca-' + orgName, crypto_suite);

        var adminUser_from_store = await fabClient.getUserContext('admin', true);

        if (!adminUser_from_store && !adminUser_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
            throw new Error('Admin does not exist.');
        }

        console.log('Admin found');
        admin = adminUser_from_store;
        console.log('enrolled user -> ' + admin.getName());

        user = {
            enrollmentID: username,
            affiliation: orgName + '.department1',
            maxEnrollments: 5,
            role: 'client',
            attrs: [{ name: 'firstName', value: 'Lohith', ecert: true }] 
        }
        var enrollmentSecret = await fabric_CA_Client.register(user, admin);

        console.log('client registered');
        console.log('Successfully registered user - secret:' + enrollmentSecret);

        var enrollment = await fabric_CA_Client.enroll({
            enrollmentID: username,
            enrollmentSecret: enrollmentSecret,
            attr_reqs: [
                { name: "firstName", optional: false }
            ]
        });

        console.log('enrollment certifiacte is ', enrollment.certificate)
        var member = await fabClient.createUser({
            username: username,
            mspid: mspID,
            cryptoContent: {
                privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(),
                signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate
            }
        });

        console.log('Member ->', member);
        memberUser = member;

        return await fabClient.setUserContext(member);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Invoking Chaincode:**

```
module.exports.putData = async function (orgName, functionName, username, args) {

    try {
        const client = await getClient(orgName, username);
        console.log('done with get client. client is ', client._userContext._identity._certificate);

        const channel = await client.newChannel('mychannel');

        let channelEventHub1 = channel.newChannelEventHub(peer1);
        channelEventHub1.connect(true);

        channel.addOrderer(order);
        channel.addPeer(peer1);
        channel.addPeer(peer2);
        channel.addPeer(peer3);
        channel.addPeer(peer4);
        const peer = [peer1, peer2, peer3, peer4];
        // var tx_id = new Transaction(client.getUserContext(username, true))
        var tx_id = client.newTransactionID(false);
        tx_id_string = tx_id.getTransactionID();

        var request = {
            targets: peer,
            chaincodeId: 'hyperCC',
            fcn: functionName,
            args: args,
            chainId: 'mychannel',
            txId: tx_id
        };

        console.log('Sending proposal');

        var results = await channel.sendTransactionProposal(request, 60000);

        let isValid = channel.compareProposalResponseResults(results[0]);
        if (isValid) {
            console.log('Endorsement success')
            var orderer_request = {
                // txID: tx_id,
                proposalResponses: results[0],
                proposal: results[1]
            };
            console.log('proposal responses are ............');

            const result = await channel.sendTransaction(orderer_request);
            // console.log('done with everything', result);
            return true;
        } else {
            return new Error('Endorsement failed.');
        }

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Test Chaincode:**

```
package main


import (
    // "bytes"

    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    // "strconv"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid"
    "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim"
    sc "github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer"
)

// Define the Smart Contract structure
type SmartContract struct {
}

type ShippingInstruction struct {
    Shipper             string `json:"shipper"`
    Consignee           string `json:"consignee"`
    NotifyParty         string `json:"notifyParty"`
    SpecialInstructions string `json:"specialInstructions"`
}

func (s *SmartContract) Init(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
    fmt.Println("inside the init function......")
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

func (s *SmartContract) Invoke(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
    function, args := stub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
    fmt.Println()
    if function == "generateShippingInstruction" {
        return s.generateShippingInstruction(stub, args)
    }
    return shim.Error("Invalid chaincode function name...")
}

func (s *SmartContract) generateShippingInstruction(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) sc.Response {
    if len(args) != 5 {
        return shim.Error("Invalid number of arguments. Expecting 5")
    }
    value, found, err := cid.GetAttributeValue(stub, "firstName")

    if err != nil {
        return shim.Error("could not do abac")
    }

    fmt.Println("value is ", value)
    fmt.Println("found is ", found)

    error := stub.SetEvent("test", []byte("hello"))
    if error != nil {
        return shim.Error("could not set the event")
    }

    var shippingInstruction = ShippingInstruction{Shipper: args[1], Consignee: args[2], NotifyParty: args[3], SpecialInstructions: args[4]}
    shippingInstructionAsBytes, _ := json.Marshal(shippingInstruction)
    stub.PutState(args[0], shippingInstructionAsBytes)
    fmt.Println("the data has been successfully added to ledger...")
    return shim.Success(nil)
}

// The main function is only relevant in unit test mode. Only included here for completeness.
func main() {
    // Create a new Smart Contract
    err := shim.Start(new(SmartContract))
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error creating new Smart Contract: %s", err)
    }
}
```

**The error is**

```
Error: No identity has been assigned to this client
    at Client._getSigningIdentity (/home/lohith/Work/fabric-samples/HyperFabric_2/hyperFabric/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Client.js:1213:11)
    at Channel.sendTransaction (/home/lohith/Work/fabric-samples/HyperFabric_2/hyperFabric/node_modules/fabric-client/lib/Channel.js:2536:38)
    at module.exports.putData (/home/lohith/Work/fabric-samples/HyperFabric_2/hyperFabric/app/app.invoke.js:172:42)
    at <anonymous>
```

The error occurs at the channel.sendTransaction(). The chaincode executes successfully inside the container but fails while returning.

Comment: What chaincode is returning? Before (sendTransaction), i mean the endorsement result?
Because i had the same issue using Java client, and it is happening only when chaincode returns fail.

Comment: Hey Bassel, when I compare the transaction proposal ( by `channel.compareProposalResponseResults(results[0]);` ) I get true as a result that means endorsements are success, right ?

Comment: can you add the code for `await getClient(orgName, username);` ?